# Date/String comparison

Tags: php, string, date

i need to compare two dates one of which is actually a string.
So i get today's date from date('d/m/y') and the other date from somewhere in my db.
This one is a string looking like 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

I don't know how to compare them, i've tried over and over again but i can't get it working.
here's the code

```
<?
  require_once '/web/ticket/src/event/Event.php';
  require_once '/web/ticket/src/ticket/Ticket.php';

  $tickets = Ticket::getTickets();
  $events = Event::getEvents();

  $today = date('d/m/Y');

  foreach($events as $k => $event) {
    $data_1 = $event['data_singolo'];
    $data_2 = $event['data_a'];

    if($today>$data_1 || $today>$data_2) {
       Event::setInvalid($event['_id']);
    } else {
      echo "evento attivo<br><br>";
    }
  }

  foreach($tickets as $k => $ticket) {
    $event = Event::getEventById($ticket['event_id']);
    if($event['valid']==0) {
      Ticket::setInvalid($ticket['_id']);
    }
  }
?>
```

PS. 'Data' means 'date';

Comment: use `strtotime` for effective date comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Using the DateTime class is a way to do it if you need special non-standard date formats. :)

```
<?
  require_once '/web/ticket/src/event/Event.php';
  require_once '/web/ticket/src/ticket/Ticket.php';

  $tickets = Ticket::getTickets();
  $events = Event::getEvents();

  $today = new DateTime("today");

  foreach($events as $k => $event) {
    $data_1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $event['data_singolo']);
    $data_2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $event['data_a']);

    if($today>$data_1 || $today>$data_2) {
       Event::setInvalid($event['_id']);
    } else {
      echo "evento attivo<br><br>";
    }
  }

  foreach($tickets as $k => $ticket) {
    $event = Event::getEventById($ticket['event_id']);
    if($event['valid']==0) {
      Ticket::setInvalid($ticket['_id']);
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was a real mess so i ended up with this.

```
<?
require_once '/web/ticket/src/event/Event.php';
require_once '/web/ticket/src/ticket/Ticket.php';

$tickets = Ticket::getTickets();
$events = Event::getAllValidEvents();

$today = date("d/m/Y");

foreach($events as $k => $event) {
 if($event['tipo_data']=='1') {

  $data_singolo = $event['data_singolo'];
  $data_singolo_chunks = array_map('intval', explode('/', $data_singolo));
  $data_1 = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $data_singolo_chunks[1], $data_singolo_chunks[0], $data_singolo_chunks[2]));

  if($today>$data_1) {      
    Event::setInvalid($event['_id']);
  }
} else {

  $data_a = $event['data_a'];
  $data_a_chunks = array_map('intval', explode('/', $data_a));
  $data_2 = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $data_a_chunks[1], $data_a_chunks[0], $data_a_chunks[2]));    

  if($today>$data_2) {      
   Event::setInvalid($event['_id']);
  }
}
}

foreach($tickets as $k => $ticket) {
$event = Event::getEventById($ticket['event_id']);
if($event['valid']==0) {
  Ticket::setInvalid($ticket['_id']);
}
}
?>
```